# Why do Typescript classes implement interfaces automatically?

Tags: class, typescript, interface

So I did the Typescript tutorial without any former JS experience. My question is in given example code, why can you pass the Student object into the greeter() function which takes a Person as parameter? The class Student never implements said interface so I wonder if in Typescript classes automatically implement interfaces. And if they do, what's the reasoning behind this? It seems pretty useless if Car, Plane and Student all automatically implement Person.

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Comment: Answer to short to be an answer: Yes

Comment: What's the purpose of that? So every single class - f.ex. Car, Plane, Account - that I would declare in this file would implement Person??? I could as well just remove the interface completely and include it in the class then

Comment: You still have to have the same fields (of the same type) as the interface declares! Unless your Plane has a firstName and a lastName, it won't be considered a valid Person

Comment: Typescript interfaces are implemented structurally so a class only implements `Person` if it has `firstName` and `lastName` properties of type `string`.

Comment: Okay but Student does not have these fields, they just seem to appear as formal parameters in the constructor but not as actual fields? Also they are not specified to be strings either...

Comment: The `public` keywords in front of the parameter names turns them into fields. The lack of type annotation means they're of type `any`; fields of type `any` are compatible with any other type.

Comment: I see. I think that is very counter intuitive, given that parameters (formal especially!) are hardly a nice way to define instance variables... So since there is only this one constructor I guess all Students implement Person and there are no non-Person students?

Comment: If you don't like parameter properties you can declare them in the class body instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interface in typescript is a pure abstract concept
in really javascript world, it doesn't has interface concept.
the interface you write in typescript won't be translated into javascript

So, for interface, it doesn't have to really implement it, just need to be in the same shape.
official explanation can be find here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Answer (score 12):

This is called [Structural Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). Essentially, relationships between types in TypeScript are never required to be explicitly declared ('named', as in nominal typing, like C#, Java and friends), they're done purely by analysing the structure of the types involved.

In TypeScript when you say that a class implements an interface, you're not actually changing the class at all, or the types of the subclasses involved, you're just asking the compiler to confirm that it does indeed already implement that interface.

As for the reasoning, the key factor here (as with many decisions in TypeScript) is that this more closely matches what JavaScript does in practice (i.e. [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - if you pass something the right shape, it'll work), so makes compatibility with existing JavaScript code far easier.

Notably this does leave TypeScript with some limitations. For example, you can't use identical but incompatible types as [marker interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) to limit input, as in Java. In Java [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and [Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) cloneable are two empty interfaces which can be implemented to mark a type as serializable or cloneable, and methods can then accept only `Serializable` parameters to ensure they get only classes which are explicitly known to be safe to serialize. In TypeScript, you can't do that: an empty interface doesn't change the structure of an object, so doesn't make any difference to the type system at all.

Comment: The "marker interfaces" you describe are already a kind of work-around, though, aren't they? That is not what the concept of an interface is for. (An empty interface should almost be a compiler error.) I read that typescript will eventually have support for decorators, which is probably a better way of doing this.

Comment: FWIW, Go-lang does something similar with interfaces: the actual classes (possibly 3rd party!!!) are NOT required to implement your interface, but the language still allows you to make an interface and check that the object-of-the-day has the needed methods/capabilities.  Even when an old 3rd party object didn't know you needed its "justDoIt(now)" method.

Comment: Structural typing is one of my favourite Go features, just getting started with typescript, and I'm glad they use this